# Conditionally plot single line with different colours in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, time-series, conditional-statements

I drew an empty plot and subsequently added a `lines()` function that draws a time series of a numeric vector. I want to change the line so as the line colour (alternatively the line type) varies binary, depending on another numeric vector containing `0` and `1`. This is what I got so far:

```
lines(x, y, type = "l",
      col = ifelse(z == 0, "black", "green"))
```

`x` and `y` are numeric vectors `num [1:2718]` listing the points to join; `x` just contains numerics from 1 to 2718. `z` is the binary numeric vector `num [1:2718]` that contains only `0` and `1`; there are 786 `0`s and 1932 `1`s in `z`. For each case `z == 0`, the line should be coloured black and in all other cases (`z == 1`), the line should be green. All three vectors have the same length.

**Problem**: So far, the line is all green, likely because the first element of `z` is 1. After I manually changed the first element from 1 to 0, the line was all black. It seems that R just takes the first element of `z` and colours the line accordingly. Using `z[i]` or `z[x]` does not change anything, the line is still all green.

I cannot think of a way to tell R to fetch each element of `z` successively and use the conditional colours accordingly while plotting along `x` and `y`. If it would be easier for any reason to use conditional line types than colours I am happy with such a solution as well. I am using base graphics.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: this? `df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20, z=rep(c(1,3),5));
plot(df[,1:2],type="n");
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ lines(df[i:(i+1),1], df[i:(i+1),2], col=df[i,3])}`

Comment: Mhh, not quite. I stored the three vectors in a data frame and assigned the third column the characters "black" and "green", respectively. The for loop works the way you wrote it but not when I use `[i, 1]` instead of `[i:(i+1), 1]` (for each column respectively) which is what I actually want. There is no error message, it's just that nothing is plotted when executing the code.

Comment: When using this `[i, 1]` you have to change `lines` into `points`. `lines` need start and end point.

Comment: Makes sense. Works when changed to `points()`. I would still rather have lines visualised but that should be possible somehow with the correct graphical parameters inside `points()`. Any thoughts on why it did not work with the code I had in the first place (the one in the original post)? Why the detour with creating a data frame first?